# OpenCV 1.x backend

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to parallelize the source code for opencv project, which has to be in pure C. I have believed till now that opencv 1.x is C based. But while going through the 1.0 source code, I saw C++ files and also `new` operators and classes have been used. Is it really C or a mix of C/C++.

Comment: Probably the real issue here is that you're still using OpenCV 1.x

Comment: lol no I have been using C++ api for a while now. Only for this project, I need to specifically use C api. The parallelising code works only for pure C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of no consequence for a normal developer using openCV.

openCV provides a C interface and that is usable regardless of it being implemented in C, C++ or assembler. It might (it is not) even be implemented in PASCAL or COBOL and exported to a library usable in C, it would be irelevant to the developers using it.

In the particular case of openCV 1.0 it is indeed implemented using C++.
C++ was designed with interoperability with C as a design goal. `extern "C"` provides that interoperability, so providing a C interface for openCV 1.0 is easy.

Consider in example cxcore.h :

```
(...omited...)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/******************************************************************************
*          Array allocation, deallocation, initialization and access to element
\******************************************************************************

/* <malloc> wrapper.
   If there is no enough memory, the function
   (as well as other OpenCV functions that call cvAlloc)
   raises an error. */
CVAPI(void*)  cvAlloc( size_t size );

(...omited... )
```

But OP is about forking openCV to parallelize it. In that case it is a very relevant question.
If 1.0 had been in C and 2.0 in C++ then there would have been advantages in using 1.0 as a base.
But such is not the case so you might as well fork from the latest openCV.

Comment: This clears things for me. Actually in this particular case, the actual implementation does matter and not only the interface, since we are building our parallelising api which works only on C source code.

Comment: Oh, so you are not using simply openCV as a library. You are forking openCV. Yes, yes, it does matter a lot in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to this question:

First, you are right, OpenCV 1.0 uses C++ *internally*.

Second, however, the *external* interface is pure C, so that it doesn't matter from a user's point of view.